# Imac12,2 and Ubuntu 16.04 issues with network NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIeNetXtreme BCM57765

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, ethernet

I have a few iMacs with dual SSDs so they are both Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and MacOSX. The issue, which is very well known, is that there is a bug on MacOSX security patch that had disabled the BCM57765 card. I had followed all the suggested steps on MacOS X but still that card is NOT enabled. Worse than that is that I cannot enable the card any longer on Ubuntu. Since Ubuntu is my main OS on these machines I only care for the ethernet card to work with Ubuntu. I can only make wiFi work on this machine now.

I am sure a lot of Ubuntu users are facing same issues with iMac hardware as per a research I did.

I have some posts here at https://discussions.apple.com/message/31196301?ac_cid=op123456#31196301

Hopefully some of you could give some hints on how to enable this card again. It was working before. I had the cable checked, switch, etc. It works with another machine just fine. It is the bad MacOS X updates that disabled this card. I had also ran diagnostics and there is absolutely no issues with that card.

Thank you in advance!

Here is some output from this machine:

```
$ modinfo tg3
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/tg3.ko
firmware:       tigon/tg3_tso5.bin
firmware:       tigon/tg3_tso.bin
firmware:       tigon/tg3.bin
version:        3.137
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom Tigon3 ethernet driver
author:         David S. Miller (davem@redhat.com) and Jeff Garzik (jgarzik@pobox.com)
srcversion:     4FC1C1E65FE27E74954CBF5
```

---

```
$ lspci -vv
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at a8400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Region 2: Memory at a8410000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=6 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=2 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=2 offset=00000120
    Capabilities: [ac] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <2us, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [13c v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-3c-07-54-0f-45-bb
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejS02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at a8400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Region 2: Memory at a8410000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=6 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=2 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=2 offset=00000120
    Capabilities: [ac] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <2us, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [13c v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-3c-07-54-0f-45-bb
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
noopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

---

```
$ lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 3c:07:54:0f:45:bb
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=57765-v1.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:a8400000-a840ffff memory:a8410000-a841ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: e4:ce:8f:65:57:c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:a8600000-a861ffff memory:a8620000-a862ffff
```

---

```
$ ifconfig 
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:07:54:0f:45:bb  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:100158 (100.1 KB)  TX bytes:100158 (100.1 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:ce:8f:65:57:c1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a0a:3478:92d8:7fc3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17959 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32329367 (32.3 MB)  TX bytes:3247075 (3.2 MB)
```

---

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i -e '\<eth' -e '\<t3g'
[    2.013036] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM957765) rev 57785100] (PCI Express) MAC address 3c:07:54:0f:45:bb
[    2.013039] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 57765 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[    2.013041] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[    2.013042] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit][    2.013036] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM957765) rev 57785100] (PCI Express) MAC address 3c:07:54:0f:45:bb
[    2.013039] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 57765 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[    2.013041] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[    2.013042] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[    2.017089] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
[    8.896491] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.017089] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
[    8.896491] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

Comment: The issue is not on the wireless. That works fine. The advised link is for wireless diagnostics. It is the ethernet BCM57765 that is the problem.

Comment: By the way, `ifconfig` shows an Ethernet interface `enp2s0` with a MAC address assigned to Apple but without any IP configuration or package transfer. Can you try to enable the wired connection in the network settings please? If that doesn't work, please describe what you tried, what went wrong and include all error and warning messages verbatim.

Comment: David, thanks for the help that is very good. When I try to enable that via DHCP or via manual configuration it says that the cable is not detected. There seems not be any errors. I will try the app you have suggested and post more information.

Comment: The issue is that the results cannot be posted here due to their size. What is the best way to post them?

Comment: David, here it is. https://paste.ubuntu.com/23747885/

Comment: Done David.
[    2.013036] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM957765) rev 57785100] (PCI Express) MAC address 3c:07:54:0f:45:bb
[    2.013039] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 57765 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[    2.013041] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[    2.013042] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[    2.017089] tg3 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
[    8.896491] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3

Comment: Nothing interesting there unfortunately.

Comment: Exactly. Interesting mystery with these iMacs.